# Testing seemless migration to Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We are moving from an on prem identity provider to Azure AD B2C. Based on [this official Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-migration), we decided to go with the seemless migration process. The only problem I have with this approach is that we cannot really test it until we are in production, because our api's route that needs to be called (to validate user's credentials against legacy idp) are not reachable from the outside in all development/integration stages (for obvious reasons).

I want to know if anyone has ever implemented this flow in real life and if so, how did you manage to test it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a test instance of your IdP. Your production env should be mirrored in terms of architecture in lower envs. Anything less is not representative.

Comment: Suri Our dev environment is similar to the production, except it's not reachable via internet (no DNS). Same for the IdP, it's a test instance pointing to a DB with fake users. So there's no way I can call it from a custom policy from Azure AD B2C plateform. I guess our only choice would be to publish the test environment. But the organisation choice might also be to drop the entire migration project (not just for this reason for other requirements considerations). We have a meetng this morning. Thanks for your answer.